# finding intersection of discs in 3D

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geometry

I have a data set of discs in 3D space. Each disc is defined by it's center and radius and Strike and Dip(Strike and Dip are the way geoscientists use for defining planes in 3D). I convert Strike and Dip to normal vector. As a result, the discs can be represented using center, radius, and normal vector.
I want to find out how many intersections each disc has with other discs. The way I'm approaching this is as follows:
for each 2 discs:
r1 and r2 are radius of the first and second discs and c1, c2 are the center points

1. check |c1-c2|<r1+r2
2. if (1) holds true, check if the normal vectors are parallel.
3. if parallel -> see if discs are in the same plane -> if yes: they intersect. if no: they don't intersect
4. if not parallel -> find the intersection line
5. find the minimum distance of c1 from the line (d1), find minimum distance of c2 from the line (d2). if d1<r1 and d2<r2 then the discs intersect. if not, they do not intersect.

Following I have attached all the functions that I'm using:
In the code: 'Easting' stands for X, 'Northing' stands for Y, 'Depth' stands for Z. I also find the minimum value in each of easting, northing and depth and subtract these values from their respective columns. I assume this will not affect the end result as it's only a translation.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy import radians, cos, sin
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import art3d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from itertools import product


#################################functions##############################3
def plane_intersect(a, b):
    """
    a, b   4-tuples/lists of A,B,C,D where
           Ax + By +Cz + D = 0
           A,B,C,D in order  

    output: 2 points on line of intersection, np.arrays, shape (3,)
    """
    a_vec, b_vec = np.array(a[:3]), np.array(b[:3])

    aXb_vec = np.cross(a_vec, b_vec)

    A = np.array([a_vec, b_vec, aXb_vec])
    d = np.array([-a[3], -b[3], 0.]).reshape(3,1)

# could add np.linalg.det(A) == 0 test to prevent linalg.solve throwing error

    p_inter = np.linalg.solve(A, d).T
    

    return p_inter[0], (p_inter + aXb_vec)[0]


def dist_point_from_line(p, q, rs):
    """
    p, q, rs  3-D points in space where
              p,q are two points on a line and rs is the point of interest
    output: minimum distance (perpendicular) of point rs from the line defined by p, q
    """
    p=np.array(p)
    q=np.array(q)
    rs=np.array(rs)
    x = p-q
    return np.linalg.norm(
        np.outer(np.dot(rs-q, x)/np.dot(x, x), x)+q-rs,
        axis=1)

def plane_parameters(S,D,x,y,z):
    """
    S,D   Strike and Dip of a plane in degrees
    x,y,z Easting, Northin, Depth of the event(center of the disc)
    
    output: parameters of the plane containing the disc
    """
    A=-cos(radians(S))*sin(radians(D))
    B=sin(radians(S))*sin(radians(D))
    C=-cos(radians(D))
    D=-((A*x)+(B*y)+(C*z))
    return A,B,C,D


def disc_intersection(df):
    for i in range(len(df)):

        a = df.iloc[i][['Northing','Easting','Depth']]
        r1= df.iloc[i][['SourceRo']][0]
        Strike1=df.iloc[i][['Strike']][0]
        Dip1= df.iloc[i][['Dip']][0]
        for j in range(i+1,len(df)): 
            print()
            print("i,j:",i,',',j)
            b = df.iloc[j][['Northing','Easting','Depth']]
            r2= df.iloc[j][['SourceRo']][0]
            print('r1:',r1)
            print('r2:',r2)
            Strike2=df.iloc[j][['Strike']][0]
            Dip2= df.iloc[j][['Dip']][0]
            centers_distance = np.linalg.norm(a-b, ord=2)
            print('centers_distance:', centers_distance)
            #print("centers_distance:",centers_distance, type(centers_distance))
            if centers_distance<= (r1+r2):
                print("|c1-c2| <= r1+r2")
                A1,B1,C1,D1 = plane_parameters(Strike1,Dip1,a['Easting'],a['Northing'],a['Depth'])
                A2,B2,C2,D2 = plane_parameters(Strike2,Dip2,b['Easting'],b['Northing'],b['Depth'])
                print("A1,B1,C1,D1:",A1,",",B1,",",C1,",",D1)
                print("A2,B2,C2,D2:",A2,",",B2,",",C2,",",D2)
                if not np.any(np.cross(np.array([A1,B1,C1]),np.array([A2,B2,C2]))):
                    print("normals are parallel!")
                    if A2*a['Easting']+B2*a['Northing']+C2*a['Depth']+D2==0:
                        print("discs are in the same plane and they do intersect!")
                        df.iloc[i,6]+=1
                        df.iloc[j,6]+=1
                    else:
                        print("discs are not in the same plane and hence they don't intersect!")
                        #planes are parallel and discs are not in the same plane => no intersection
                        pass
                else:
                    print("planes not parallel!")
                    p, q= plane_intersect([A1,B1,C1,D1], [A2,B2,C2,D2])
                    print("c1 from intersection line:", dist_point_from_line(p, q, np.array(a)))
                    print("c2 from intersection line:", dist_point_from_line(p, q, np.array(b)))
                    if dist_point_from_line(p, q, np.array(a)) <= r1 and dist_point_from_line(p, q, np.array(b)) <= r2:
                        print("intersection found!!!")
                        df.iat[i,6]+=1
                        df.iat[j,6]+=1
                    else:
                        print("intersection NOT found!!!")
                        #although the planes intersect eachother, discs do not!
                        pass
            else:
                #There is no way that two discs placed farther than r1+r2 can intersect eachother.
                print("|c1-c2| <= r1+r2 is not true!")
                pass
    return df      

##########################################################
df =pd.DataFrame([[281017,1941326,8923,282.18,64.27,32.874017],
                  [281019,1941351,8902,47.51,60.60,35.826773],
                  [281107,1941313,8818,285.14,70.81,52.854332],
                  [281078,1941385,8865,42.60,40.11,35.170605]], columns=['Northing', 
                 'Easting','Depth', 'Strike', 'Dip', 'SourceRo'])
df=df.loc[:,['Northing', 'Easting', 'Depth', 'Strike', 'Dip', 'SourceRo']]
df['num_intersections']=np.zeros(len(df))

north_min=df['Northing'].min()
east_min=df['Easting'].min()
depth_min=df['Depth'].min()
df['Northing']=df['Northing']-north_min
df['Easting']=df['Easting']-east_min
df['Depth']=df['Depth']-depth_min
north_min=df['Northing'].min()
north_max=df['Northing'].max()
east_min=df['Easting'].min()
east_max=df['Easting'].max()
depth_min=df['Depth'].min()
depth_max=df['Depth'].max()
r_max=df['SourceRo'].max()
north_min-=r_max
north_max+=r_max
east_min-=r_max
east_max+=r_max
depth_min-=r_max
depth_max+=r_max

new_df = disc_intersection(df)
```

The first two discs actually intersect. I have included an image of the 4 discs in the space for you reference.

I have noticed that d1 and d2 change when I add or remove a disc in the DataFrame, which is not mathematically correct, but I don't know which part of the code is problematic.

[image: image of the discs]

Comment: So far, it appears that you need to first learn basic debugging.  You've posted nearly 150 lines of code.  You state "I don't know which part of the code is problematic" -- *why* don't you know?  You clearly stated various conditions that you're algorithm is supposed to check, but you haven't shown whether or not your program correctly determines those conditions.  Use `print` statements; learn a debugger; reduce the code to the computational portions, and isolate the problem.  You also haven't demonstrated what parts of the code *do* work correctly, only that a pair of distances "change".

Comment: @prune by "I don't know which part of the code is problematic" I mean I have checked each part separately and they all seem to work fine. I have also used print statements (you can see them in the code).
The reason why I shared all of the code is that there might be something that I don't know and is affecting the result!

Comment: Excellent; you have a lot of evidence to include in the research -- and you *should* have some places you can replace with stubs.  As the posting guidelines say, "Make it easy for others to help you."  Don't leave us to start from scratch on this much code.